# Using a STL container to store Treeview data

Tags: c++, stl, treeview

i'm looking for a C++ STL container class to keep the treeview parent/child node strings but  when a node is deleted from tree control, do i have iterate through all the container class elements to find that selected one and then delete it? what's the best to keep the data updated in container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [STL set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/), which is efficient in operations like `insert` and `delete` in O(log n) time.

e.g.

```
set<TreeNode> a;
a.insert(aTreeNode); // insert
a.erase(aTreeNode); // delete
```